# How to return columns of dataframe held in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary `dict` of dataframes `df1, df2, df3`, I want to return the columns of any dataframe (they are always the same)?

I want to use them as a graph titles, I've tried a few variantions of;

`titles = dict.items(df1.columns)`

I know this is likely very simple but my noob brain can't see the answer.

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Do you know how to use dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# if you don't know dict keys
titles = dict_df[[*dict_df.keys()][0]].columns

# if you know dict keys you can use this
titles = dict_df['df1'].columns
```

Comment: First solution works best for me, nice and simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below?

```
for pntr in dict.keys()
    print(pntr," has columns",dict[pntr].column.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all the columns header of your dataframes is the same, you can just take one dataframe and then get columns header of it.

```
titles = dict['df1'].columns.tolist()
```